# How to add go pkg to existing repo?

Tags: git, go, github, multi-module, go-modules

I have this [repo](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art) in github that have library for [cpp](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/tree/master/art-cpp) and [go](https://github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/tree/master/art-go) in same repo. Now how can I create `go.mod` in the `go` to import it ?

I searched google about that but all are have Separate repo. How can i do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1️⃣. init module in sub dir:

```
cd /art/art-go

go mod init github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go
```

2️⃣. add missing and remove unused modules for `go.mod` file

```
cd /art/art-go

go mod tidy
```

3️⃣.❗️ Because you have [multimodule](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) project, you have to add [version tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) with submodule declaration (`<submodul_dir_name>/<version>`) to submodule witch fit to [Semantic Version](https://semver.org) specification

```
git commit -a - m "art/art-go - some changes"
git tag art-go/v1.0.0
git push
git push --tags
```

4️⃣. ☝ thus, you can import it in other projects

```
module go mod init github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/otherproject

require github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go v1.0.0

go 1.15
```

4️⃣. ✌ or `get` it

```
go get github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go@v1.0.0
```

*Output*

```
go: finding github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go v1.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, As you said i changed the folder structure but when i import throws error like `but does not contain package github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go/anixt`  in [go plagground](https://play.golang.org/p/IM4PRsKR2fv)

Comment: Did you add version tag `art-go/v1.0.0`?

Comment:  `go get github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go@v0.1.0` works fine  `go: downloading github.com/srilakshmikanthanp/art/art-go v0.1.0`